# Деплой Python Телеграмм-бота на AWS

Tags: python, telegram-bot, развертывание, telebot, amazon-web-services

Нужно задеплоить Телеграмм-бота на AWS (желательно на Американский или Немецкий сервер). Бота написал с помощью PyTelegramBotApi на Python. Опыта в деплое нет, методом тыка разобраться не получилось. Искал информацию в интернете, на ютубе - только устаревшее, 3-х летней давности видео. У бота есть БД (SQLite3), дополнительных файлов в его директории на 50 мб. Просьба - помочь мне с деплоем: либо видео скинуть, либо связаться лично, либо расписать, как это делать.

Comment: посмотри на ютубе как на heroku заливать,думаю подойдет

Comment: код бота на github или bitbucket, на aws через git clone стянуть. через far можно подключиться к aws и скопировать оставшиеся файлы которые нельзя помещать в репозиторий

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете разместить своего бота на heroku.com 
В youtube есть подробные инструкции, плюс есть подробные инструкции на сайте heroku.com. 
 
План действий:

1. Посмотреть примеры на ютуб
2. Зарегистриоваться на heroku.com.
3. Следуя инструкциям на сайте, залить бота на heroku.com.